STO (ESTO) Einstein Send Time Optimization sends outdide of the STO Window
we are seeing from a Sunday June 9 email that went thru a 12 hour STO window in Journey Builder that contacts received the email well AFTER that window closed.  You can see in the 1st attached image that this contact exits STO at 10:04 pm but the email was received at 1:15 AM.  This seems to be cooberated by looking at the contact in All Contacts (2nd attached image) that shows a 12:15 (CT) email send.
So - what can explain this?  180k exited STO at approx 10:00 pm but it sould not take 2 hours & 15 minutes for marketing Cloud to process that volume.
Anyone else seeing any similar issue?


